# regular expression - match

Tags: php, regex

I need to match an alphanumeric word.  It can contain "-" but not at the end or start, and "-" must not be repeated (like "--") and the word length must be between 2 and 24 characters.

some examples:

```
adfg
asd-asdasd
asd-asd-asd
```

and these should not be matched:

```
-asd
asd-
-asd-
-asd--asd-
```

Comment: `(\w+(-\w+)*){2,24}` note that `\w` includes underscore. You can use `[0-9a-zA-Z]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most difficult things about using regexes is resisting the lure of excessive cleverness.  You've got two separate, incompatible tests to perform.  Length:

```
/^.{2,24}$/
```

...and composition:

```
/^[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)*$/i
```

While it *might* be possible to come up with a regex that will perform both tests in one pass, there's no need.  Just do one of them as a lookahead:

```
/^(?=.{2,24}$)[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)*$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this PCRE reg exp:

```
/^(([0-9a-z]+-)*[0-9a-z]){2,24}$/i
```

Comment: Then why `/^(([0-9a-z]+-)*[0-9a-z]){2,24}$/i.test('ss-ss-ss-ss-ss-ss-ss-ss-ss-ss-ss-ss-ss-ss-ss-ss-s')` returns true, if it works great? )

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions depend on the platform you are using, and they are not very good for matching sizes (if you try to determine a specific length, you will probably loose flexibility, unless you are checking more standardized inputs, like dates: `\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})`.
But something like:

```
[a-z]+(-[a-z]+)*
```

may give you an idea for your problem.